# Getting error while reindexing in magento2

Tags: magento2, cms, catalogsearch, reindex, page-builder

While re indexing in magento2 getting below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Stage\Preview::isPreviewMode() must be of the type boolean, null returned in /var/www/html/Project/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Model/Stage/Preview.php:132
```

Do anybody know what isPreviewMode work for in pagebuilder?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm getting the same

Comment: @BelgoCanadian Not excatly. But if you are using Mirasvit's elasticsearch extension and you have enable CMS index. you can add custom cms page in ignore list.
How it's work for me is like that

Comment: @rutvee-sojitra any solution on this, please

Comment: @gajjalasandeep yes read above comment. It's work for me

Comment: @rutvee-sojitra I am not using Mirasvit's elasticsearch extension